# Ajax request not working in IE Browser

Tags: ajax, jstree

We are using this Code For ajax call using `JStree`
but When we are using IE it not Working 
- Requests work just fine the first time When we try
- As data is modified, that realize that but still seeing old results

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "/",
                    method: "GET",
                    context: document.body
                    }).done(function () {
                    if (obj != "") {
                        obj(chkedValue);
                    }
```

Comment: I have also Used Cache False Property but it Still not Working

Comment: What is `chkedValue`?

Comment: where is obj defined?  is it supposed to be function (obj) instead of function ()?  we need some more context/code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding timestamp to url to prevent caching in IE.

```
var ts = new Date().getTime().toString();
url += "?t=" + ts;
```